# Stop overlapping of a Math.random() div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, I'm making my own little "game", but I'm having a problem. In the "game" You have a text in the middle of your screen that by clicking the heart goes to it, the heart fades out, you get scores, and in 5 seconds it respawns, etc.. Now, I made a div around all of that called "game-area", and I want the heart to stay inside of it, I don't want it to overlap or I don't want part of it hidden, I want it completely inside the game_area div. The heart coordinates of where it spawns are set by a Math.random(), I'm doing all this in jQuery.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    $("#text").animate({
        marginTop: y,
        marginLeft: x
    }, 300);
});
$("#heart").click(function() {
    $("#heart").fadeOut(2000);
    var heart_pos = $("#heart").position();
    heart_top = heart_pos.top;
    heart_left = heart_pos.left;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#heart").css({
            marginTop: Math.random() * 500 - 117,
            marginLeft: Math.random() * 500 - 100
        });
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#heart").fadeIn(2000)
    }, 5000)
    get_heartPos();
});

function set_heartPos() {
    var heart_pos = $("#heart").position();
    heart_top = heart_pos.top;
    heart_left = heart_pos.left;
    $("#heart").css({
        marginTop: Math.random() * 900 - 117,
        marginLeft: Math.random() * 500 - 100
    });
}
window.onload = set_heartPos();

function get_heartPos() {
    var heart_pos = $("#heart").position();
    heart_top = heart_pos.top;
    heart_left = heart_pos.left;
    setTimeout("get_heartPos()", 3000);
}
window.onload = get_heartPos();
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="game_area">
            <div id="heart">

            </div>

            <div id="text">
                Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
#game_area {
    width: 950;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#text {
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    cursor: default;
}

#heart {
    display: block;
    width: 117px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: url("heart.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    float: left;
}

::selection {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: you just forget to post relevant code...

Comment: just one more questions, can we have basic css of the div and the heart? like position: relative, top left and padding please

Comment: Added it in, in case you haven't noticed yet but I'm sure you did xD

Comment: do you really mean: `Math.random() * 500 - 117`
or could it be that you mean: `Math.random() * (500 - 117)` ??

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have been my problem, didn't even think of that *facepalm* Thanks so much